# automatically say yes to "you placed a large amount of text on the clipboard.Do you want this text to be available to other applications after you quit Word"

Tags: microsoft-word, clipboard

when closing word after copying a large amount of text I get message "you placed a large amount of text on the clipboard.Do you want this text to be available to other applications after you quit Word"

how can I set this to always answer yes without interupting me?

Comment: If only there was an option without Third Party Tools or Macro's... I do tons of programming and would gladly take the "risk" of losing data vs this annoying prompt. It should be as simple as a setting in Office.... But what it should be and what it is are not the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[ClickOff](http://www.johanneshuebner.com/en/clickoff.shtml)** is just terrific.

when the windows pops up the next time, hover the mouse over the button you want to press (Yes) and press CTRL + ALT + D to add this action to the list of warnings you want to intercept, from now on this warning won't bother you anymore.

[image]

[image]

*ClickOff is freeware.*

Answer (score 2):

This [**AutoHotkey**](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script will do the trick

```
While 1
    {

    WinWait, Microsoft Office Word, You placed a large amount of text on the Clipboard
    WinActivate
    ControlClick Button1

    }
```

`Button1` is the control name for the "Yes" button.